# Minus two arrays in python which is similar to bsxfun in matlab

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matlab

I have two np.arrays, say `A=np.array([1,2,3])` and `B=np.array([1,2,3,4])` for example. I want to compute a new array `C` such that the first row of `C` is the first element of `A` minus every element in `B`, the second row of `C` is the second element of `A` minus every element in `B` and the last row of `C` is the third element of `A` minus every element in `B`. Is it possible to code it without using any for loop or numpy repeat? I know that we can use bsxfun in matlab. I search but I cannot obtain satisfactory answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
c = (A - B.reshape(4, 1)).T
```

Output:

```
>>> c
array([[ 0, -1, -2, -3],
       [ 1,  0, -1, -2],
       [ 2,  1,  0, -1]])
```